# JPA 2: Benefits of @TableGenerator

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, annotations

What are the benefit of @TableGenerator Technique to generate the primary keys?
Why we use this technique and how to fetch the data using third table that use to store the sequence name and value of generator?

Comment: what you have searched and [what you have tried](http://mattgemmell.com/2008/12/08/what-have-you-tried/)

Comment: i am confused why we use tablegenerator technique ? for table generator we create extra table to save the generator sequence and generator value . what is the reason of extra table and to retrieve the data from table the third table is used or not?

Answer (score 3):

From the link. http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Java_Persistence/Identity_and_Sequencing#Table_sequencing

> There are several strategies for generating unique ids. Some strategies are database agnostic and others make use of built-in databases support.
>   JPA provides support for several strategies for id generation defined through the GenerationType enum values: TABLE, SEQUENCE and IDENTITY.
>   The choice of which sequence strategy to use is important as it affects performance, concurrency and portability.

So the choice of using table generators frees you from using database specific features. This makes it easy to migrate the database to some other db provider later on.
So the decision  should be made based on whether you want to later on migrate database providers, how much performance you will sacrifice for that etc.

Answer (score 0):

TABLE generator has many benefits :

1. You can have a single table to store primary key counters for multiple entities if you compare with SEQUENCE generator.
2. You can have custom character prefixed primary keys which are sequential if you compare with IDENTITY generator.
3. It makes your database easily migratable as the counter would be present in the underlying table

On how to fetch data from underlying table of TABLE generator, here is one article on [how to implement a custom TableGenerator with a prefix](https://www.truiton.com/2024/02/spring-boot-hibernate-jpa-generationtype-table-vs-sequence-strategy-with-mysql/#Custom-TableGenerator). But there are many available on the internet.